# how to group rows in mysql according type?

Tags: php, mysql, optgroup

=) im just bothered of this problem.. how to group the rows in mysql according to type well here is my example input and output for this..
 lets just say that i have these in my database

```
|Name | address |  type | 
a1    add1      t_spot
c2    add2      t_acc
e3    add3      t_res
b1    add1      t_spot
d2    add2      t_acc
f3    add3      t_res
```

and i want to group it by their type and put it in select box using php
lets just assume this will be the expected code

```
<select name='all'>
<optgroup label="t_spot">
<option value=''>a1</option>
<option value=''>b1</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="t_acc">
<option value=''>c1</option>
<option value=''>d1</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="t_res">
<option value=''>e1</option>
<option value=''>f1</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

please help ..thanks a lot it'll be appreciated..

Comment: What do you want query or PHP script  ?  And BTW What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Clearly you're not creating a mysql group there...

Answer (score 1):

In your query, `ORDER BY type`.

Then, when reading the data, keep track of the current type, and when you see a change you know to end the current block and start the next.  Pseudocode:

```
select * from table order by type
cur_type=''
while(more rows)
    if (type != cur_type)
        if (cur_type != '')
            terminate optgroup block
        start new optgroup block
    write option
if (cur_type != '')
    terminate optgroup block
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to run multiple queries with a where clause based on the type:

```
select * from table where type = 't_spot'
select * from table where type = 't_acc'
...
```

Or you need to query all rows and split them by type in your code based on the type. Loop through the results and put them into separate lists used to populate your html. An ORDER BY will probably be helpful here so you can keep track of when the type changes as you loop through the results.